# HTTPS request using Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, https, request

I'm new in node.js

And I have a problem to get html body by https request. I'm using the following script:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://icobench.com/ieo',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

==========================================

I have also tried to get page by the following code:

```
const https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'icobench.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/ieo/',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

but it gives back the error:

```
statusCode: 503
headers: { date: 'Mon, 16 Dec 2019 08:05:21 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close',
  'set-cookie':
   [ '__cfduid=de0d50bfceb3fee0883f10b9f6d1440341576483521; expires=Wed, 15-Jan-20 08:05:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.icobench.com; HttpOnly; Secure',
     'PHPSESSID=tkt1clieuc55bq0ilvho2b0dr3; path=/' ],
  expires: 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'retry-after': '300',
  'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'expect-ct':
   'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': '545f26d6cbcbbdb9-AMS' }
```

What should I change in my code to get html body to parse it after?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But where are you actually `request`ing it? `request(options, callback)`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not include function call. I've changed the code one minute ago.

Comment: you need to await for result. or add something to callback function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: With another http URL it works well. But with https something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the server.

```
const https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 443,
  path: '/ieo/',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

https.createServer().listen(8084)
```

This is the update:

```
https.createServer().listen(8084)
```

You may get the following error code `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`, depends on the browser. Just keep in mind that you need a SSL certificate. ( You can go with a self signed ssl certificate ).

This link will help you to get through it: https://flaviocopes.com/express-https-self-signed-certificate/

Please check this link out too:
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the comments. I have changed my code as follow:

```
const {parse} = require('node-html-parser');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const URL = 'https://icobench.com/ieo';
const BASE_URL = 'https://icobench.com';

async function getDOM(url) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      uri: url,

      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
      },
    };

    request(options).then((html) => {
      let dom = parse(html);
      resolve(dom);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
      console.log(err);
    });

  });
  return promise;
}



let domMain = await getDOM(URL);
```

Ant it doesn't work without headers:

```
headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
}
```

I hope it will useful for somebody.